# WooCommerce: Get name and variation from a Subscription order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to display the name of the subscription product in the overview of my active subscriptions. At the moment, the page shows only the subscription order number with the function `$subscription->get_order_number()`

I printed the array behind `$subscription` but it seems that the array has no information about the subscription product or the ordered variation.

Is there a way to display the name and the variation of the ordered subscription product?

Displaying the order number only, is not very helpful for the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Subscription (just as WC_Order objects) can contain **one or more products as line items**. So that's why you can see this data.

So Just as WooCommerce orders you need to iterate through the Subscription items to get the product name:

```
// Set here your subscription ID (if needed)
$subscription_id = 319;

// Get the WC_Subscription object (if needed)
$subscription = wc_get_order($subscription_id); // Or: new WC_Subscription($subscription_id); 

// Iterating through subscription items
foreach( $subscription->get_items() as $item_id => $product_subscription ){
    // Get the name
    $product_name = $product_subscription->get_name();
}
```

This code is tested and works

> Subscription products are an extension of WooCommerce products. So all methods available for WC_Product are usable…

---

Related official developer documentation:

- Introduction: [About subscriptions objects](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/#section-5)
- [Subscription Products vs. Subscriptions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/data-structure/)

Comment: This is what exactly I was looking for. But Another thing. How I get the product ID from above code ? Whats the change or whats the key to use ? get_id ?